# Load single image by map API and draw overlays

Tags: openlayers-2, web-mapping, tiles, google-maps-api, image

I have an image which  I want to make it zoomable and dragable in browser, and draw some overlays like lines and markers on it.

So I wonder if I can use the map api like Google map or openlayers to load the image. Then I can use the draw feature provided by the API to add overlays.

Since the image size is not fixed ,some of them are almost 100M. So I may have to generate tiles first, but the image have no coordinates, so I do not know if it is possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are your images georeferenced?

Comment: No,just a static image.

Comment: I would try to convert your image to svg wich can me dragged easily in maps

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is definitely possible.

QGis has a QTiles plugin, which uses gdal2tiles under the hood, AFAIK.

Then you can use leaflet/openlayers to read your tiles from the created directory structure.

Comment: But how about the coordinate of the tiles ?

Comment: Just fake it. georeference the image so the corners get UTM coordinates, export with QTiles plugin. QTiles generates a leaflet-based viewer if instructed. You can use this as a base for further work.

Comment: I found this:https://developers.google.com/kml/articles/raster#translate. Seems `gdal_translate` can do this job.

Comment: hummm what about the dragable part? How tiles could be dragged? svg wont be a better option?

Comment: Just try it. Import a raster image to QGis, assign a projection/fake georeference, the use QTiles plugin to export.